# Float values in a list become string when converting the list to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list (scores) that contains float values and I want to convert it to a numpy array. However, after converting it, the type of the values changes from float to string. This is what I have written:

```
scores = [5.0, 5.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
import numpy as np 
scores = np.array(scores)
scores = ['5.0' '5.0' '4.0' ... '5.0']
```

I have tried to convert the values to float once again:

```
scores = np.asarray(scores, dtype=np.float64, order='C')
```

However, the following error appears:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

How can I convert a list to a numpy array in a way that the type of the values doesn't change?

Comment: Show `scores`, if not all, enough so we can understand the kinds of elements in that list.  A python list can contain anything, strings, numbers, other lists etc.  The error tells me that the list contains strings that do not represent numbers.  That kind of error message usually shows the string that caused the problem.  Did you intentionally cut that off?  Why?

Comment: The original list contains only float values.

Comment: Your numpy array is also having `floats`. Where did you see the strings? Check `scores.dtype`. Should be `'numpy.float64'`.

Comment: You are using `numpy` and `np`. If you want to use `np` do `import numpy as np`.

Comment: The type of the values in the array has changed to string.

Comment: @MayankPorwal, checking the `dtype` of an array is sufficient.  `type` on elements of an array is not the same as `type` on elements of a list, since array values are not stored by reference.

Comment: @hpaulj I got that as soon as I posted the comment. I've updated my older comment, removed new one.

Comment: There must be at least one string in that list.  Which is it?

Comment: No. They are all floats.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they are converting to a string I tried your code and added a simple line of addition between two indices and the result is not in a string means they are not concatenated they are actual decimal numbers.

```
scores = [5.0, 5.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
import numpy 
scores = numpy.array(scores)
print(scores[0]+scores[1])
```

Comment: This is what I get when I try your code: "5.05.0"    The strings are concatenated. The floats have not been added.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a numpy list of `string` dtype ,  use `y = scores.astype(np.float)` to convert it to `float` type